# self-adjoint extension of the momentum operator in an infinitely deep potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Theta parameter arises when calculating self adjoint extensions of the momentum operator of a particle in an infinnitely deep potential, what does this means physically?

Comment: You should probably add context sio as to make your question self-contained.